# Android - different aspect ratios of imageviews in scaled and original images

Tags: java, android, scale, aspect-ratio

I have two imageviews:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_small"/>
```

logo_small is just a resized version of logo (width and height have been resized to 75%). I've noticed that logo.getGlobalVisibleRect(logoRect) returns dimensions of different aspect ratio, compared to logo_small.getGlobalVisibleRect(logoSmallRect). Why is it so?
EDIT:
Here's some more code, as requested:

```
 final ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
 final ImageView logo_small = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_small);
 Rect logoRect = new Rect();
 Rect logoSmallRect = new Rect();
 logo.getGlobalVisibleRect(logoRect);
 logo_small.getGlobalVisibleRect(logoSmallRect);
 Log.d("LOGO", "logo aspect ratio " + ((float)logoRect.width()/ logoRect.height()) + ", logo_small aspect ratio " + ((float)logoSmallRect.width()/ logoSmallRect.height()));
```

And what I get is:

```
 D/LOGO﹕ logo aspect ratio 1.0682492, logo_small aspect ratio 1.2081686
```

Comment: We have no elements to help you. Show some code...

Comment: @Tobor There's nothing special about it, but I've updated question

Comment: Now we have something to work on.

Comment: Are you sure you maintained the same asèect ratio (75% and 75%) AND resolution (dpi)? If so, then it could be due to approximations. See what happens if you move (float) OUTSIDE the outer parenthesis.

Comment: after casting only width to float and then dividing it looks ok. Thanks for suggestion Tobor